# What is the difference between the two "worlds" when going thru the day/night wormhole at the altar?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

In Pokémon Sun and Moon, when you've finished the game you can switch day and night by going though the wormhole at the altar where you've caught the box legendary. Are there any more differences when going through the wormhole, excluding the day or night difference? For example, the altar of the sunne and altar of the moone switch when going through the portal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to open the portal, you need to have the legendary Pokémon that commands the time you're trying to get to. If you want to change the time to daytime, you need Solgaleo in your party, and if you want to change the time to nighttime, you need Lunala in your party. This means that without trading, you can only travel through the portal during real life nighttime, but if you have both legendary Pokémon, you can change the time at will. You can also always return to the world you originally came from.

The only differences between the worlds are the time, and an event which

> lets you obtain Cosmog at the Lake of the Sunne in Sun and Lake of the Moone in Moon.

Comment: "If you want to change the time to daytime, you need Solgaleo in your party, and if you want to change the time to nighttime, you need Lunala in your party." -- This is incorrect, the only mon you need in your party is the one on the box. I have sun, and I've gone to the other dimension, did the thing in your spoiler, and gone back to my own time, all without even having lunala seen in my pokedex.

Comment: @Pyritie "You can also always return to the world you originally came from." Basically what it means is that if you have Solgaleo in Moon, you can change the time from night to day.

Comment: But there aren't any differences  where buildings change like the Altar of the Sunne/Moone when going through the wormhole?

Comment: @nelson2tm No, just the names of the Altars and the Lakes. Everything else is identical, locationwise.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Ok, though your wording made it sound like you needed both. The altar/lake will have the different sun and moon symbol on it but that's all.

Comment: @Pyritie You need both if you want to change the time anytime. You can't move away from your original world during daytime in Sun or nighttime in Moon without trading.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Yes you can, you just need the legendary you got as part of the story. Like I said, I haven't even caught a lunala, yet in my sun I can go back and forth as much as I want.

Comment: @Pyritie You cannot go through the wormhole into the alternate world if it's daytime in the original world in Sun. I've said this before. Without trading you can only change the time during real nighttime.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer Hm, I guess I must've only tested this at night then.